# Problems using EF tools due to application attempting database access

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 app using EF Core 2.2.

I have some background worker threads which I start in `ConfigureServices()`. These threads depend on the DbContext and on other services which I register in `ConfigureServices()`.

I found that when I try to use `Add-Migration`, the EF tools cause these threads to run, which in turn throw exceptions in the `Add-Migration` output because the threads try to access a database object that does not yet exist.

It appears the migration is created successfully, however, it makes using the tooling difficult because it appears to fail (exceptions in output, process does not exit, etc).

Some options I see to avoid this:-

a) Somehow detect in `ConfigureServices()` that the database does/does not match the context (i.e. is "up to date") and act accordingly.

b) Start my worker threads somewhere else that will not get invoked when my app is run by the EF tools. Keeping in mind that starting these threads require a `ServiceProvider` with the same scope I'm building in `ConfigureServices()`.

c) Detect in my app that I'm being called by the EF tools and avoid launching the worker threads.

I'd appreciate any advice on the most appropriate strategy and the best method of achieving it.

Comment: [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) - probably [From a design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-a-design-time-factory)

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks, that looks like exactly what I'm after; do you want to make that an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core tools use different strategies for creating derived `DbContext`, explained in the [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) section of the documentation.

Looks like currently you are using [From application services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-application-services). But according to the problem explanation, the most appropriate in your case seems to be [From a design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-a-design-time-factory):

> You can also tell the tools how to create your DbContext by implementing the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>` interface: If a class implementing this interface is found in either the same project as the derived `DbContext` or in the application's startup project, the tools bypass the other ways of creating the DbContext and use the design-time factory instead.